# How to log out all users after server stops running in django

Tags: python, django

I am building a website with Django. I have created users using the built-in django user model. I have a login page where each user can login as well as a button to logout. I want to automatically log out the user that is logged in when I stop the runserver command. This is what I've tried so far but it is not working:

myapp/signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(request_finished)
def handle_server_shutdown(sender, **kwargs):
    logout()
```

myproject/**init**.py

```
import myapp.signals
```

Comment: `request_finished` is at the end of a HTTP request, not when you stop the server. You also log out after the login request. You can just clear up the requests after stopping the server.

Comment: just truncate the django_sessions table...